# Setting folder permissions programmatically

Tags: c#, permissions

I'm trying to copy a file to the directory `C:\Windows\Win32` in Windows 7 using C#, but the operating system does not allow me to. I've written a program for solving the problem, but it throws an exception on the line where I set access control: `di.SetAccessControl(ds)`.

The exception message is:

> "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."

My code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\Win32");
            FileSystemAccessRule fsar = new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            DirectorySecurity ds = null;
            if (!di.Exists)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Windows\Win32");
            }

            ds = di.GetAccessControl();
            ds.AddAccessRule(fsar);
            di.SetAccessControl(ds);
            File.Copy(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg", @"C:\Windows\Win32\Desert.jpg");
            Console.WriteLine("successfully copy!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your code snippet.

Comment: You must run your program as administrator due to it being a protected folder. If that is not possible, change your location from the windows folder...